# How do I create a login system for an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, sql, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to make a login system for my cocoa app. How would I do this? I know it involves SQL, but I know nothing of SQL. I want the user to register or login. It would be easier if apple had a source code for this kind of thing, but I don't think they do.

Best Regards,

Kevin

Comment: Making a login system does not necessarily involve SQL, so I think you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: How do I make a login system then? I want something so new users could register and login from a server.

Comment: What is your server - what software does the app connect to?

Comment: Apple does have sample code for SQLite (see SQLiteBooks) and Core Data, but the others are right, a database framework has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: I don't mean this to sound harsh but if you don't know where to start, you probably aren't quite ready to plunge into an iPhone app. Conceptually, you need a screen with a form that can capture the information required for the login, it would need to be sent somewhere to verify its validity (or perhaps validated internally) and then you'd need to display the results to the user.

Comment: Sorry, but this question does indicate that you are missing some fundamental concepts on software development.

We can probably be of more help if you describe a bit more exactly what your application does and what its for so we can suggest some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Implement the login system on the server.  Then all you have to worry about in your app is:

1. send them to your website via URL to
   sign up
2. query for a name and password
3. if name and/or password is incorrect more than three times, go to 1
4. user is logged in.  Do something.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the keychain on the iPhone to securely store and retrieve passwords. Here's excellent code from [Sci-Fi Hi-Fi](http://log.scifihifi.com/post/55837387/simple-iphone-keychain-code). You prompt for a password, store it securely in the keychain for later comparison. Pretty simple. Documentation on the site.